# In Python MapReduce, can mapper output objects of classes?

Tags: python, mapreduce

I am really new to MapReduce. I found examples of M/R in Python that mapper and reducer both output using `print string`. I wonder if we can pass an object of self-defined class as I hope to overwrite the > operator so as to control the sorting in M/R.

Comment: Sure, it all depends on the methods your class defines to enable the split and combine operations. Override `__gt__()` if you really want to overload `>`

Comment: instead of "print string", what is the syntax to "print object"?

Comment: `print repr(object)` if `object` does not implement `__str__()`  but the print in the examples is just to show you where data is shifted around through the M/R flow...

Comment: @cowbert Thx. repr() still outputs string, right? If I overwrite the > operator, it wouldn't work if I output string I think.

Comment: `repr()` could output a string depending on if `__repr__()` is overriden :) by default it outputs a string though. I'm not sure where you are going with this though. M/R is just an implementation of scatter-gather pattern. Are you just looking for a generic way to "output" the object? Like `lambda x: x`?